# convert "23/11/2016" date into "MM/dd/yyyy" format in C#

Tags: c#

```
string valid= "22/11/2016"; 
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(valid, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);//not valid date time format
```

when i am trying to convert date in "MM/dd/yy" format it gives error that inputted string not in valid date time format.Please help

Comment: That date is in `dd/MM/yyyy` format, use that to parse it.

Comment: Are you explicitly trying to convert it into `MM/dd/yyyy` format or are you just using the wrong format when parsing the date?

Answer (score 0):

format should be `"dd/MM/yyyy"`,note that `d` for date and `M` for month, 22 can't be a month

```
string valid= "22/11/2016"; 
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(valid, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);//
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
string valid = "22/11/2016"; // should be in this format dd/MM/yyyy
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(valid);
```